# MongoDB unique index is not working

Tags: java, mongodb, groovy

I'm using Mongodb from Java.

I create a collection and an index like this:

```
collection = mongoClient.getDB(DB_NAME).getCollection(COLLECTION_NAME)
collection.ensureIndex(new BasicDBObject(['customerReference': 1, 'unique': true]))
```

when I check in the mongo shell i see:

```
{ 
   "v" : 1, 
   "key" : { "customerReference" : 1, "unique" : true }, 
   "ns" : "diagnostics.diagnosticData", 
    "name" : "customerReference_1_unique_" 
}
```

but i can still insert duplicates:

```
{ 
  "_id" : ObjectId("52f3ba8a7d841c01680e0bc5"), 
  "customerReference" : 3, 
  "data" : "original data", 
  "created" : ISODate("2014-02-06T16:38:34.191Z") 
}
{ 
  "_id" : ObjectId("52f3ba8a7d841c01680e0bc6"), 
  "customerReference" : 3, 
  "data" : "duplicate data", 
  "created" : ISODate("2014-02-06T16:38:34.194Z") 
}
```

why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possibly you haven't created the index properly.

Do it from the DB shell by executing the following statement:

```
db.refs.ensureIndex({customerReference: 1}, {unique : true})
```

Here, when I try to insert the document with the duplicate `customerReference` I receive an error, saying:

> E11000 duplicate key error index: test.refs.$customerReference_1  dup key: { : 3.0 }

And when I execute the `db.refs.getIndexes()` command, I get:

```
{
    "v" : 1,
    "key" : {
        "customerReference" : 1
     },
     "unique" : true,
     "ns" : "test.refs",
     "name" : "customerReference_1"
 }
```

which shows that the unique index is created properly, but differs slightly from yours.

**Update**:
When you're ensuring the index in the collection, you're making **only one** `BasicDBObject`, which will result in:

```
"key" : { "customerReference" : 1, "unique" : true }
```

Here, the value of the `key` shouldn't contain the `unique` attribute.

The `unique` attribute should be placed within the `index` document, like in mine code:

```
"key" : {
     "customerReference" : 1
 },
 "unique" : true
```

To create the index properly, you will have to provide **two** `BasicDBObjects`:

- one for `{customerReference : 1}`
- one for `{unique : true}`

Comment: but you can see it was created because i queried the index collection. Can you see something wrong with that?

Comment: yes, i see the difference now. The key to index should not have included the unique field. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm using mongoose for JavaScript but I think that the solution that I found well also work for other languages...
When you connect your database with the application add this option: "audoIndex: true"
for example in JS we'll do something like this:

```
const options = {
// your options go here
...
// this code is the solution
audoIndex: true
}
mongoose.connect(DB_URI, options);
```

I also dropped the collection that I have problem with and recreated it to make sure that it will work.
I found this solution at: https://dev.to/emmysteven/solved-mongoose-unique-index-not-working-45d5
I also tried solutions like "restart MongoDB" but didn't work for me.